# How to reset some outlier value according to the mean value for all of the other numbers in one column?

Tags: r, dplyr, outliers

I need to replace outlier values that are either greater than 2 times of the mean value or smaller than 1/2 of mean of all the other numbers  in the column with the mean value.

For example, I have a dataset DT including two columns:

- Date = {1-1-2019,1-2-2019,1-3-2019,1-4-2019,1-5-2019,1-6-2019}
- Price = {2,3,2.5,2.7,28,20}

I need to replace the outlier values(28 and 20 here) with the mean value of all the other values in Price columns. So basically I need to do the following:

```
DT$Price[DT$Price>2*mean(2,3,2.5,2.7)|DT$Price<0.5*mean(2,3,2.5,2.7)] <- mean(2,3,2.5,2.7).
```

Could anyone please kindly give me an advice how to deal with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is

```
mean_p <- mean(df$Price)
inds <- df$Price > (2 * mean_p) | df$Price < (mean_p * 0.5)
df$Price[inds] <- mean(df$Price[!inds])
```

However, note that in the example shared `mean_p` is `9.7` and all the `Prices` in the dataframe are either greater than `19.4` (`2* 9.7`) or less than `4.85` (`0.5 * 9.7`).

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c("1-1-2019","1-2-2019","1-3-2019","1-4-2019",
                          "1-5-2019","1-6-2019"), 
                 Price = c(2,3,2.5,2.7,28,20))
```

Comment: Thank you , is it possible to set the mean_p to the avaerage of all the other values that are not belong to the outlier group, say mean_p is the mean of (2,3,2.5,2.7) but don't count in 28 and 20.

Comment: @Cherry but how do you know which values are in outlier group before checking for `inds` ?

Comment: @Cherry What I mean is how do you know that you don't have to count 28 and 20 while taking mean?

Comment: You reminded me! I found the function boxplot function helps here. Thanks a lot!